# Jesstab command for adding an instance to a class

Tags: protege, jess

The JessTab command `make-instance` creates a new instance of a class. I do not want to create a new instance, but instead use an existing one and set it to be also an instance of another class. Is it feasible to do it with JessTab commands?

Answer (score 0):

A make-instance like this

```
(make-instance paul of Person (name "Paul") (age 42))
```

creates a shadow fact, which has a single OBJECT slot referencing the object, and a slot defining the class, e.g., `(is-a Person)`. Apart from any object *naturally* being also an object of its superclass as well, an object cannot be made to be an instance of another class.

Maybe you are trying to solve a problem that can be better addressed using another approach - why don't you ask about that in the first place?